# Is there an easier way to find the row with a max value?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a schema where these two tables exist (among others)

**participation**

```
+------+--------+------------------+
| movie| person |       role       |
+------+--------+------------------+
|    1 |      1 | "Regisseur"      |
|    1 |      1 | "Schauspieler"   |
|    1 |      2 | "Schauspielerin" |
|    2 |      3 | "Regisseur"      |
|    3 |      4 | "Regisseur"      |
|    3 |      5 | "Schauspieler"   |
|    3 |      6 | "Schauspieler"   |
|    4 |      7 | "Schauspielerin" |
|    4 |      8 | "Schauspieler"   |
|    5 |      1 | "Schauspieler"   |
|    5 |      8 | "Schauspieler"   |
|    5 |     14 | "Schauspieler"   |
+------+--------+------------------+
```

**movie**

```
+----+------------------------------+------+-----+
| id |            title             | year | fsk |
+----+------------------------------+------+-----+
|  1 | "Die Bruecke am Fluss"       | 1995 |  12 |
|  2 | "101 Dalmatiner"             | 1961 |   0 |
|  3 | "Vernetzt - Johnny Mnemonic" | 1995 |  16 |
|  4 | "Waehrend Du schliefst..."   | 1995 |   6 |
|  5 | "Casper"                     | 1995 |   6 |
|  6 | "French Kiss"                | 1995 |   6 |
|  7 | "Stadtgespraech"             | 1995 |  12 |
|  8 | "Apollo 13"                  | 1995 |   6 |
|  9 | "Schlafes Bruder"            | 1995 |  12 |
| 10 | "Assassins - Die Killer"     | 1995 |  16 |
| 11 | "Braveheart"                 | 1995 |  16 |
| 12 | "Das Netz"                   | 1995 |  12 |
| 13 | "Free Willy 2"               | 1995 |   6 |
+----+------------------------------+------+-----+
```

---

I want to get the movie with the highest number of people that participated. I figured out an SQL statement that actually does this, but looks super complicated. It looks like this:

```
SELECT titel 
FROM   movie.movie 
       JOIN (SELECT * 
             FROM   (SELECT Max(count_person) AS max_count_person 
                     FROM   (SELECT movie, 
                                    Count(person) AS count_person 
                             FROM   movie.participation 
                             GROUP  BY movie) AS countPersons) AS 
                    maxCountPersons 
                    JOIN (SELECT movie, 
                                 Count(person) AS count_person 
                          FROM   movie.participation 
                          GROUP  BY movie) AS countPersons 
                      ON maxCountPersons.max_count_person = 
                         countPersons.count_person) 
                               AS maxPersonsmovie 
         ON maxPersonsmovie.movie = movie.id
```

The main problem is, that I can't find an easier way to select the row with the highest value. If I simply could make a selection on the inner table and pick the row with the highest value on `count_person` without losing the information about the movie itself, this would look so much simpler. Is there a way to simplify this, or is this really the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way without subqueries:

```
SELECT m.title
FROM movie.movie m JOIN
     movie.participation p
     ON m.id = p.movie
GROUP BY m.title
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

You can use `LIMIT 1` instead of `FETCH`, if you prefer.

Note:  In the event of ties, this only returns one value. That seems consistent with your question.

Comment: Thank you, this actually worked, is so much simpler and better to understand. Great solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rank` window function to do this.

```
SELECT title
FROM (SELECT m.title,rank() over(order by count(p.person) desc) as rnk
      FROM movie.movie m
      LEFT JOIN movie.participation p ON m.id=p.movie
      GROUP BY m.title
     ) t
WHERE rnk=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT title
FROM   movie.movie
WHERE  id = (SELECT   movie
             FROM     movie.participation
             GROUP BY movie
             ORDER BY count(*) DESC
             LIMIT 1);
```